# Conditional sum / sumifs in R

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements, sumifs

I want to left join/merge/aggregate a count of a measure in Table B onto Table A based off the dates.

Ex.
TableA:

| A.Member | A.DateBeg | A.DateEnd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 202001 | 202012 |
| 001 | 202101 | 202112 |
| 003 | 202001 | 202012 |
| 003 | 202101 | 202112 |

TableB:

| B.Member | B.Date | B.Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 202011 | 5 |
| 001 | 202102 | 7 |
| 001 | 202103 | 3 |
| 003 | 202007 | 4 |
| 003 | 202011 | 2 |
| 003 | 202012 | 3 |

What I want to do is basically a left_join with like a sum or summarize where the by is a conditional statement.

Something along the lines of:
Sum(B.Count) Where B.Date >= A.DateBeg AND B.Date < A.DateEnd

I'm thinking something like:

```
TableC <- left_join(TableA, TableB, by = c("A.Member" = "B.Member", "B.Date" >= "A.DateBeg" & "B.Date < "A.DateEnd"), sum(B.Count))
```

Resultant TableC should look like:

| A.Member | A.DateBeg | A.DateEnd | Sum(B.Count) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 202001 | 202012 | 12 |
| 001 | 202101 | 202112 | 3 |
| 003 | 202001 | 202012 | 9 |
| 003 | 202101 | 202112 | 0 |

Really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 0):

This could. be done with `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
fuzzy_left_join(TableA, TableB,
   by = c("A.Member" = "B.Member", "A.DateBeg" = "B.Date",   
       "A.DateEnd" = "B.Date"), 
   match_fun = list(`==`, `<=`, `>`)) %>% 
 group_by(A.Member, A.DateBeg, A.DateEnd) %>% 
 summarise(Sum = sum(B.Count, na.rm = TRUE),  .groups = 'drop')
```